# listview scrolling to end after showing Contextual action bar

Tags: android, android-listview

When i do a long click on an item in the list view(which triggers the contextual action bar to show up), the list view automatically scrolls to the end. This behaviour is very irritating if the user had selected an item after scrolling up.

Using breakpoints i verified that this happens after `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` in the `MultiChoiceModeListener` implementation has completed. But i am not sure what code gets executed after this that causes the behaviour.

Removing the `transcriptMode` attribute from the list view layout resolves the issue. But i don't want to remove it as it is required to scroll automatically when the data has changed in the cursor. Any ideas what is causing the problem?

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Get the chat messages list view from the layout
            lv_chatMessages = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.listview_chat);

            // Instantiate the adapter for the chat messages
            adpt_chat = new ChatMessagesAdapter(getActivity());

            // connect the adapter to the list view
            lv_chatMessages.setAdapter(adpt_chat);

            //Implement multi choice mode listener for the list view
            //only if Android API 11 or higher 

            if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {

                //Enable selection of multiple chat messages
                lv_chatMessages.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

                //Handle Action mode events
                lv_chatMessages
                        .setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,
                                    MenuItem item) {
                                switch(item.getItemId()){
                                case R.id.delete_menu :
                                    long[] selected_IDs = lv_chatMessages.getCheckedItemIds();
                                    int deletedRows = deleteMessages(selected_IDs);
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), deletedRows + " message(s) deleted",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return true; // true indicates the menu selection is handled. no further
                                                    // system handling required
                                default :
                                    return false;
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode,
                                    Menu menu) {

                                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                                inflater.inflate(R.menu.chatsession_contextmenu, menu);
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0,
                                    Menu arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                    int position, long id, boolean checked) {

                                mode.setTitle(lv_chatMessages.getCheckedItemCount() + " selected");


                            }

                        });
            }
...
..

}
```

**The list view layout :**

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_chat"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_input"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `transcriptMode` attribute seems to be the only solution. I use the below code whenever i require an automatic scroll to the end :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                lv_chatMessages.setSelection(lv_chatMessages.getCount());
            }
        },100);
```